# Problem with Linq and c# api and db tables and relations

Tags: c#, linq

I need help, I should get the following result:

Data for employees with projects he worked on and tasks he worked on.

Here are the tables from DB:
Employee table has ID;

Project table has ID;

Tasks table has EmployeeID and ProjectID .

Relations are going from Employee to Tasks and from Project to Tasks.

I thought I can use something like this:

```
  var data = DB.Employees
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Id,
        x.Username,
        Projects = x.Tasks.GroupBy(e => e.Project.Name).Select(grp => new 
        {
            Project = grp.Key,
            Tasks = grp.ToList()
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

I need API to push data to client side, but the actual result is not working for me.

```
public class Employees
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
   public List<Project> Projects { get; set }
}
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set }
}
public class Task
{
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you create `expected JSON response` and what you are getting now

Comment: What's wrong with your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your database with classes :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database DB = new Database();

            var results = (from e in DB.Employees
                           join t in DB.Tasks on e.ID equals t.EmployeeID
                           join p in DB.Projects on t.ProjectID equals p.ID
                           select new { employee = e, task = t, project = p }
                          ).ToList();
            var employees = results.GroupBy(x => x.employee.ID).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Database
    {
        public List<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employees
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Task
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ty for help but I need something like this

```
public class Employees
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
   public List<Project> Projects { get; set }
}
public class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set }
}
public class Task
{
    public string details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ty for help but I need something like this: 
 public class Employees
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
       public List<Project> Projects { get; set }
    }
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
  public List<Task> Tasks { get; set }
    }
    public class Task
    {
        public string details { get; set; }
    }

Comment: The code I posted is how entity is setup.  The entity classes are table in the database.  The class shows the fields in the table.  The database contains a list of rows for each table.

Comment: I updated code to group by employees which is what I think you need.